# Connectivity Issue to graphql.contentful.com

Tags: reactjs, next.js, azure-devops, graphql, contentful

i would be grateful if someone could help me on this:

i am currently experiencing issues reaching graphql.contentful.com on azure pipeline, please see error below:

Connection error :

```
{"message":"request to https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/XXXXXXXX/environments/master failed, 
reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.42.49:443","type":"system","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT"}
Retry after 3.111379880664569 seconds
```

Did anyone else have a similar experience, and what would you recommend as a next step/solution?

1. I tried calling graphql.contentful.com from my local machine, and I haven't received any timeout errors yet.
2. i also ran the request 100 times through postman, each time receiving status 200